# nginx: Take action on proxy_pass response headers

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

I'd like to use nginx as a front-end proxy, but then have it conditionally proxy to another URL depending on the MIME type (Content-Type header) of the response.

For instance, suppose 1% of my clients are using a User-Agent that doesn't handle PNGs. For that UA, if the response is of type, image/png, I want to proxy_pass again to a special URL that'll get the PNG and convert it for me.

Ideally I'd do this without hurting performance and caching for the 99% of users that don't need this special handling. I can't modify the backend application. (Otherwise I could have it detect the UA and fix the response, or send an X-Accel-Redirect to get nginx to run another location block.)

If this isn't possible or has bad performance, where would I look to start writing a module to achieve the desired effect? As in, which extension point gets me closest to implementing this logic?

Edit: It seems like I could use Lua to perform a subrequest then inspect the response headers there. But that'd mean passing every request through Lua which seems suboptimal

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm sure there could be valid reasons to do what you want to do, your actual `image/png` example is not as straightforward as it may look.  Browsers no longer include `image/png` in their `Accept` HTTP request headers like they've used to in the old days when png was new, so, you'd have to have the whole detection and mapping tables of the really-really old browsers.

Additionally, from the architecture perspective, it's not very clear what you are trying to accomplish.

- If this is static data, then why are you proxying it to the backend in the first place, instead of serving the static data directly from nginx?  Will the `\.png$` regex not match the affected request URIs?  Couldn't you solve this without involving a backend, or even by rewriting the request without sending the wrong one to the backend first?
- If this is really dynamic, then why do you need to waste the time for making a request only to receive a reply of an unacceptable type, instead of having the special-case mapping tables based on your knowledge of how the app works, and bypassing the needless requests from the start, instead of discarding them later on?
- If the app is truly a black box, and you require a general purpose solution that'll work for any app, then it's still unclear what the usecase is, and why the extra requests have to be made, only to be discarded.

If you're really looking to mess with only 1% of your traffic as in your image/png example, then perhaps it might make sense to redirect all requests from the affected 1% of the old browsers to a separate backend, which would have the logic to do what you require.

---

Frankly, if you want to target the really-really old browsers, then I think png support should be the last of your worries.  Many webapps include very complex and special-purpose JavaScript that wouldn't even work in new alternative browsers with new User-Agent strings, let alone any old webbrowsers that didn't even have png support.

Comment: PNG was more of an example. Another one might be converting text/html for search engines that can't run JavaScript. The goal is to mess with a tiny % of the traffic but I'm not sure if a response needs messing with until I get the response - nginx is at the edge and has no assets. I got something working using several internal rewrites and Lua.

Comment: Converting JavaScript for search engines is also a questionable usecase -- it's generally something that Google explicitly prohibits, and it's also not very clear how you expect to be able to be smarter than google at the conversion of random apps, especially with the design where you simply abandon the first request after it is already processed by the backend.  I think you should simply have two backend, and redirect to either one, depending on what action must be taken -- it would likely be much simpler than trying to write your own module.

Comment: Google actually explicitly tells you to convert pages for their engine. https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification - Google, for whatever reason, has so far declined to make their crawler be a full browser, so it obviously cannot handle new apps that go full JS, for better or worse. The problem is that you don't know if a request needs special processing until you see the Content-Type of the response. I'll see if I can post a short version of what we came up with using Lua. It's not too hard, just a bit convoluted.

Comment: @MichaelGG, thanks for pointing out the ajax-crawling spec; however, this then comes back to the points in my answer -- you should address this with multiple backends, where each request will only go to either one of them, not both.  If you have enough knowledge of the app to convert the pages to ajax-crawling, then surely you can also also deterministically predict what `Content-Type` will the replies from the original backend be, based entirely on the original request.  So, I still don't see a use-case to look at `Content-Type` reply from the backend, to conditionally make a second request.

Comment: We'd use a headless browser (as-a-service, BromBone) to make the request and assemble responses of content-type html. We don't actually use escaped fragment since it's annoying, but the fact that Google encourages it seems to indicate it's fine to make an HTML snapshot for them for any given page. So /bla/bar comes in and it might be an image or an HTML page about bla-bar. We won't know until we get the response. Once we get the response, if it's HTML, we pass the request off to the render backend, which hopefully has it prerendered (by crawing on its own).

Comment: @MichaelGG, ok, now we're talking; but I still don't understand why do you need to make that first request which you then discard; why not redirect Googlebot directly to the special backend -- this backend will make the request by itself, and then will either use your headless browser-to-html, or pass the request directly to the client; sounds like a simpler and more robust and compartmentalised architecture than discarding the first reply from within nginx.

Comment: Because the special backend can't serve up images and other large resources. Otherwise yeah, it'd just be "if $ua ~= google proxy_pass specialbackend" and done. It might be better to make the backend cache and return all resources, but the frontends already have GBs of cache loaded and ready so it seems wasteful and maybe slower which might penalize SEO. But certainly cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

So according to  http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24http_HEADER. I assume you can have something along the lines of
if ($content_type ~ 'whatever your content type') {
proxy_pass 'ur_url'
}

Would that be something that works for you?

Comment: That's for the request header - in this case I need to see the response header after proxy_pass is done to determine if the content needs processing (like if it's HTML, JS, image, etc.)

Comment: So, please let me know if I understand this clearly. You need to proxy _pass certain requests to your URL. But if that request contains a specific header, you would need to send it to another URL. Am i right?

Comment: If the *response* contains a specific header, I need to send it to another URL. I currently have it working with content_by_lua, doing a subrequest to a location that proxy_passes, then conditionally doing another subrequest to another location that proxy_passes. But this means the response headers and body, I am writing out via Lua. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way.